# Bugged aab recently, but apk just fine

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, google-play-internal-testing

i am currently trying to make my first android game. Right now i am at internal testing. There's no problem of playing it until recently even though i am not making any changes to the app. When i try to launch it, the app closed with message that the app is bugged. I tried with other device, but it get the same error. When I try the apk version of the app, it worked just fine without any error. I am only getting the error when using the uploaded aab version for the internal testing. What step can I take to troubleshoot this error ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you use any app protection like dexguard?

Comment: I don't think that this Q&A is useful for anybody, as it completely lacks the context. Just pretend that you would know nothing and see how useful the content might be for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem : I added implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' in the dependencies section of my app level build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle)